# Error: Cors ao integrar nodejs e Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, front-end

Estou com um problema que preciso tratar, mas não estou conseguindo nenhuma solução até o momento.

Tenho uma aplicação em NodeJs que desenvolvi em #ExpressJS e enfrento alguns problemas relacionado ao CORS do Browser.

Em meu index.js do meu backend em node, me encontro no seguinte cenário em um trecho da minha configuração:

```
const originWhiteList = [
  'http://localhost:4200',
];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    const isWhiteListed = originWhiteList.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, isWhiteListed);
  },
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

E minha aplicação Angular, importei o modulo `import { BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';` definindo as seguintes configurações do import do app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
    { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: CustExtBrowserXhr },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    SuportService
  ],
```

A classe CustExtBrowserXhr, criei manualmente:

```
import { BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustExtBrowserXhr extends BrowserXhr {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  build(): any {
    const xhr = super.build();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    return <any>(xhr);
  }

}
```

Logo, deixei de receber o erro do CORS, mas tenho erro 404:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/suport 404 (Not Found)
core.js:1673 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:3000/suport", ok: false, …}
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
next @ core.js:4319
schedulerFn @ core.js:3555
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:195
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:133
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3539
(anonymous) @ core.js:3846
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3783
onHandleError @ core.js:3846
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:191
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:485
timer @ zone.js:2054
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2075
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2090
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
hostReportError @ hostReportError.js:3
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:167
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.js:80
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/OuterSubscriber.js.OuterSubscriber.notifyError @ OuterSubscriber.js:13
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._error @ InnerSubscriber.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.js:60
onLoad @ http.js:1556
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3815
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
(anonymous) @ http.js:1628
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:28
(anonymous) @ subscribeTo.js:21
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:6
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:70
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:67
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:50
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
(anonymous) @ scalar.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:42
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:28
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:23
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:23
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:23
push../src/app/dashboard/suport/suport.component.ts.SuportComponent.send @ suport.component.ts:29
(anonymous) @ SuportComponent.html:32
handleEvent @ core.js:10258
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:11351
debugHandleEvent @ core.js:11054
dispatchEvent @ core.js:7717
(anonymous) @ core.js:8161
(anonymous) @ platform-browser.js:995
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:3815
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:496
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
```

Agradeço se alguém me ajudar...

Comment: Veja que esta na lista a URL: `http://localhost:4200` e você esta acessando `http://localhost:3000/suport` esta correto a porta ? Não seria 4200 ?

Comment: A minha url de origem é localhost:4200... eu fiz o teste pelo Postman e da certo... isso quando eu contrui a API... só não esta funcionando a integração do angular e o nodejs... mas a porta que estou acessando é 3000 mesmo!

Comment: Entendi, agora precisa ver como esta configurada a rota  se é `GET` ou `POST`.